# Custom icons for the different mime-types in LXDE/PCManFM (open desktop)

Tags: linux, lxde, desktop-environments

I want to create new mime-type (text/something) for some kind of files. I know how to make it, but I don't know how to make the file manager to display different icons for these file types?

I am using LXDE and PCManFM, but some general solution would be better of course.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the new mimetype `text/x-foo` and assume the files all end in `.foo`.
First, we need a mimeinfo file.
It's a small XML file called `x-foo.xml` that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="text/x-foo">
        <comment>FOO file</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.foo"/>
        <icon name="foo-icon"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

This line here is key:

```
<icon name="foo-icon"/>
```

since it tells applications like file managers
to look for an icon called `foo-icon.png` or `foo-icon.svg`.
To install the mimeinfo file, we run this command:

```
$ xdg-mime install --mode user x-foo.xml
```

Now you should see the XML file here:

```
~/.local/share/mime/text/x-foo.xml
```

Next, let's update the mime database.

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

Finally, let's install the icon.
One way this can be done is with the `xdg-icon-resource` command.
For example, if you have a 48x48 PNG icon called `x-foo.png`, do this:

```
$ xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 48 x-foo.png foo-icon
```

Now you should see it here:

```
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/foo-icon.png
```

However, `xdg-icon-resource`
[does not support SVG images](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/-/issues/82),
and in practice this accomplishes the same thing:

```
$ cp foo-icon.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/mimetypes/
$ cp foo-icon.svg ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/mimetypes/
```

(That's not a typo: put the SVG file in the `48x48/mimetypes` folder
and the menus and panels will be perfectly happy.)

Finally, update the icon caches.

```
$ update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons
```

Now your custom icon for your custom mimetype should show up in all file managers.
(You may need to press F5 to refresh the icons in any open directories,
or perhaps close and re-load all running instances of the file managers.)

Here's the before and after:

[image: generic icon]
[image: foo icon]

Sources / related:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238924/assign-an-icon-to-a-custom-mimetype
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/how-to-change-a-file-type-icon-in-xfce-thunar
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585997/assign-an-icon-to-a-custom-mimetype
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=770142